# How to convert rsa key to pem using X.509 standard

Tags: ssh, openssl, azure

I've converted an rsa key to pem using the following command

```
openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -outform pem > id_rsa.pem
```

However when I try uploading this key to my ubuntu server hosted on Azure I get an error

```
The certificate is in an invalid format. X.509 standard format in a .cer or .pem file is supported.
```

What is the correct way of converting an rsa key to pem format?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get any errors using this command? Is your `id_rsa.pem` empty?

Comment: It is not empty

Comment: How would you do your conversion though?

Comment: This method is working for me. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Azure only accepts .pem or .cer keys so I can't use my id_rsa key

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/linux-use-ssh-key/) site itself:

```
openssl req -x509 -key ~/.ssh/id_rsa -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -out id_rsa.pem
```

This will convert your private key into a public key that can be used with Azure.